# How to sort by Date from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I have a php page which allows a user to sort pieces of information by several factors. A new requirement is to sort by "all items which have been registered in the last 15 days". I store my dates in the MYSQL table as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

The information is passed and picked up on the same page using the $_GET variable but I am unable for some reason to get the code to work. I have looked on numerous website but am unable to find a solution that works.

Ultimately, the script would work as follows:

select all persons who's KDATE is within 15 days of today's date (e.g., if today is 8/19/2010, everybody who registred from 8/04/2010 and on would appear).

My script so far (which does not work) is:

```
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
     $query = "SELECT * 
                 FROM persons 
                WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY) <= KDATE 
             ORDER BY KDATE ASC";
}
```

### Update 1:

`KDATE` IS TEXT - i apologize but the KDATE is stored as TEXT

### Update 2:

The answer provided by Colin solved my issue. I will look into trying to convert the data into datetime format but am hoping the group can provide realistic benefits of doing so.

Thank you all again

Comment: You mean the KDATE field is a VARCHAR?

Comment: Store your dates using the MySQL `Date` (or `DateTime`) type and you won't have these issues ;-)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: That's *so* **crazy**, it might just work =)

Comment: @ircmaxell - I agree but this is not possible retroactively for a page I am taking over. Perhaps when I get the free time to pull all current dates, then reorganize I can but for now, unfortunately this is where I'm stuck. 

It should be noted, several places the date needs very specific display format (which breaks the mysql date() function format of yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: God lord, TEXT?!  Man that's overkill for a value that's 10 characters long

Comment: @OMG - I am new to database programming and creation - what is the ideal solution? The site uses TEXT types for nearly every field (about 20)

Comment: @JM4: Use the appropriate data type - DATE only has the month/day/year; DATETIME adds the time portion, TIMESTAMP is a synonym for DATETIME...

Comment: @OMG - i was primarily referencing your astonishment for using TEXT over other options when I have seen no issues and cannot find any true benefit on the net

Comment: @JM4: Can't find a benefit?  You can't run date functionality on date data stored as VARCHAR/TEXT without converting it first - it's a) bad - bad data means needing to fix it b) won't perform well when the data isn't bad because indexes can't be used because c) you have to change data types to get access to the functionality.  On top of that, TEXT supports 4,000 characters - way overkill.

Comment: some people say my Z06 is overkill but its always nice to tear up the road a little ;)

Comment: @JM4: There's a difference between overkill and just plain wasteful/inefficient.  It would be like bringing a nuclear missile to a knife fight.  Sure, it's more powerful, but it's also a lot harder to move around with (and hence slows you down a lot)...  And it's completely wasting the resources at hand...

Comment: Oh and @OMG: The `TEXT` data type supports up to 65,536 characters (I say up to, since it depends on the characters being stored).  And it's not just overkill, it's inefficient since the data isn't even stored with the row (so doing selects on it will thrash the drives with seeks since it can't just use the row buffer).  Only use `TEXT` if you know you need more than 255 characters. Otherwise use either `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` (Which store their data in the row itself)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a really bad idea to use VARCHAR instead of DATE if you want a collumn with dates only.

If you want to use a string as a date, you'll need to convert it with [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and you might wan't to use [those instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to correctly format your date.

This should do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons 
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY) <= STR_TO_DATE(KDATE, "%c/%d/%Y")
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(KDATE, "%c/%d/%Y") ASC
```

Comment: this only orders the data, it does not return any results relatively to my main query

Comment: Be advised that this style query will not be able to use indexes.  Which means it will require a full table scan for every single query.  If you have lots of rows, or lots of these queries it will bring your server to its knees *VERY* quickly...  This will work to solve your problem, but the better solution would be to change `KDATE` to a `DATE` column data type...

Answer (score 2):

Because `kdate` is VARCHAR, you need to use [STR_TO_DATE to change it to a DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

You need to fix `kdate` data that does not fit that pattern (mm/dd/yyyy) before running this:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM persons 
   WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY) <= STR_TO_DATE(KDATE, 'm/%d/%Y')
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(KDATE, 'm/%d/%Y') ASC
```

- This means that an index on `kdate` is useless, because of having to change the data type.

Once it's a DATETIME, you can use [DATE_FORMAT to change the format as you like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: so if I understand correctly - you are saying that my overall purpose is impossible as long as my dates are in VARCHAR format?

Comment: @JM4: Not impossible.  Try the query, but it's very possible you will get an error because at least one kdate value doesn't match the date format.  So you need to fix those before the query will work.